# Incomplete automation of 2 clicks in selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide, katalon-studio, katalon-recorder

I used selenium IDE(katalon plugin) in chrome.
I have a school db of 300 students.

I need to update 2 fields in every student profile -2 drop down menus. Select "no" in both and click "Save". I automated it in the plugin. Now, I don't know how to go to every profile and do same.
The right way is to use some while loop.

The db is in this form:

- https://e.edu.kz/nedb-passport/student?school=3659&student=4314369
- https://e.edu.kz/nedb-passport/student?school=3659&student=6546456
- https://e.edu.kz/nedb-passport/student?school=3659&student=4785691

I did a pretty stupid thing - I simply change the student ID at the end and run the script, click 'play' in the plugin.

[image: tttt]

This is not proper automation, how do I do this?
Maybe switch to code and write all the selenium cmds in java?

Comment: Did You know how findElements works ??? You do not have to specify every id from table in your script. You could just click on elements of table.
Provide more code. It would always be simpler.